# cURL 'rc' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: curl, visual-studio-2015, rc

I've looked everywhere for the answer to this, no luck. I'm trying to build cURL for visual studio 2015.

`nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static VC=14 debug=no`

After a couple of seconds of building it, it says

```
   'rc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'rc' : return code '0x1'
   Stop.
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
   Studio 14.0
   \VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
   Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have 'rc' directory added to your path. For me rc.exe was in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64". Once I added that to Environment Variables, the command worked. Hope that helps.

For example:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64
```

Answer (score 0):

For x64 Use following on VS 2015 comman prompt

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 8.1
```

For x86 Use following on VS 2015 comman prompt:

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 8.1
```